# MySQL Import CSV, Convert Date Format - Best Practice

Tags: mysql, datetime, csv, import

I am writing a series of SQL scripts to import large datasets in CSV format. I know that the syntax:

```
STR_TO_DATE('1/19/2013 5:11:28 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %l:%i:%s %p')
```

will convert the incoming date/time strings correctly, like so:

```
2013-01-19 17:11:28
```

One dataset that I am bringing in has 240,000 records with 78 fields/columns, with at least 16 of those columns being DATETIME fields.
I will be performing this import on a periodic basis, using different dataset.
For each import, I wil rename the tables for backup and start with clean, empty new ones.
My question is this: in terms of best practices, which is the better approach to take on the imports?

1. Perform the date conversions as I bring them in using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE
2. Bring all of the data into VARCHAR fields using LOAD DATA..., then go back and convert each of the 16 columns separately

I *think* that I can write the script to use either approach, but I am seeking feedback as to which approach is "better".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert all of the columns in several simple passes:

1. Import the data as-is storing your ad-hoc dates in a `VARCHAR` column.
2. Use `ALTER TABLE` to create the date columns in the correct `DATE` or `DATETIME` format.
3. Use `UPDATE TABLE` to do the conversion from the raw column to the `DATETIME` column.
4. Delete the original raw columns.

The alternative is to pre-process the CSV file before import which side-steps all of this.